# How do you differentiate software between TEST and PROD environments?

Tags: development-process, versioning, production, development

We have a TEST and PROD environment. TEST and PROD are nearly identical, and obviously software first ends up in TEST before getting approved to go to PROD. Our software is primarily Windows Applications.

I'm wondering what the best way is to differentiate an application that is running in TEST vs one that is running in PROD. This would be a visual differentiation to the end user. My first thought would be version number, but then it seems like you'd be maintaining two sets of numbers.

Comment: `if (server name is "test") display "TEST"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything that is **a clear indication at all times** (not just a splash screen, for instance) when running the application.  For WinForm applications, that could be appending "Test" onto the title bar where you have the application name.

Another common and more obvious indicator could be the use of colors.  A certain window color for production (that you want end-user UX friendly), but an obviously different window color for Test or other pre-prod environments.

The color trick is a common SQL DBA/developer practice.  Connecting to production SQL instances and your query window bar is red.  Non-prod and it is green.  It requires an extra layer of ignore to make a mistake.